# The current identity, with the name 'admin' and the identifier <ID> has not been registered

Tags: backup, hyperledger, identity, hyperledger-composer

I'm trying to do a full backup of a Hyperlerger composer instance, so as many tutorials said I've saved orderer and peer production folders, then restore it using Docker volumes but when I try to run componser rest server (or any other command) I get:

> Connection fails: Error: Error trying to ping. Error: transaction returned with failure: Error: The current identity, with the name 'admin' and the identifier '26929e0ec17e93fcb6d22cc057d<>43061962760e7f23ebaf7df527', has not been registered

Haven't found any way to bypass it, I have admin and network cards used to create the first network, tried re-import with no luck.
Any other thing that I can try?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using composer (deprecated) and want to restore the backup from scratch, you have to also copy and restore the ENTIRE .composer folder located at ~/.composer.
Hope it helps.